# How to achieve the following sql query in influx?

Tags: sql, influxdb, influxql

Given a SQL query below with an `IN` clause, is there a way in influx to achieve the same output produced by this?

```
SELECT * FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country IN (SELECT Country FROM Customers)
```

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it works on the whole selected rows. Remove those extra parentheses to make the code clearer, i.e. `...(select distinct Country from...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Influxql does not support IN clause with SELECT statement. Refer [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/spec/#select):

One option for you is to demoralize your measurement by flagging(adding additional column) the point in measurement-suppliers which has corresponding matching point within measurement-customers.